# On the use of "have" to denote have in mind

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

A native English speaker(I am not) used the phrase: "I have a teacher". I was surprised because I didn't think he went to school. However, he told me that by "have" he meant "have in mind". Can "have" be used this way. It seems like a recipe for misunderstandings

Comment: What was the context of him saying "I have a teacher"?

Comment: I had told him about a teacher from my childhood and he wanted to tell me about an experience of his.

Comment: It certainly seems unusual: past tense would be standard. There are various reasons you might use present test for a historical event, such as historical present, or possibly if it's someone you're still in contact with (e.g. "I've an old teacher I still see sometimes").

Comment: Thanks, it is interesting how subtle language is. Your example showed how important context is. Though it probably is preferable to rewrite your example to something less cramped like: "I sometimes see my old teacher" and avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: This seems a very unnatural sense. "I have a teacher" would normally only be used (1) if this fact was remarkable ... say the speaker was a professor of linguistics) or (2) if following dialogue was present (... "She really makes English very clear". // If your associate had started by setting a hypothetical scene ("Let's say I'm at senior school. I have a teacher. [...]") the usage becomes fine.